# libclang.dylib causing Xcode to crash

Tags: xcode, crash, building

Sometimes when I try and build a project in Xcode, roughly 1 in 10 times, it crashes and quits. I then get an error box which says: "Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the libclang.dylib plug-in". Xcode will also sometimes crash randomly with no error report. I have never heard of libclang before, what should I do?

Comment: I'm also getting the Same Error with 4.3. I filed Bug Report: 10923185

Answer (score 0):

try installing latest Xcode 4.0.2 version

Comment: Yes... Xcode 3 is better then Xcode 4.. Xcode 4 has lot of bugs.. lot of unexpected crashing..

Comment: I currently have Xcode 4.0 (Build 4A304a). If I was to downgrade to Xcode 3, I wouldn't be able to use the function in Xcode 4 right? If so, what functions have actually been added to Xcode 4?

Comment: there are lot of things added in xcode4 ... actually all the interface is different .. and your current project also will not open in xcode 3 .. because of different project format..if you decided to use xcode 3 then you have to start your project from scratch.. you should try installing xcode 4.0.2 ...